# Can I identify live or neutral wire with Klein CL1000

Tags: voltage

I don't have one of those simple voltage detectors but I do have a [Klein CL1000](http://www.kleintools.com/catalog/discontinued-products/400a-ac-clamp-meter) meter and I need to identify the live and neutral wires from a plug in a socket.

[image]

It's a two prong socket in Central America, 120 Vac 60 Hz.

How can I identify the live or neutral wire of a CL1000 with only a clamp meter?

Comment: Oh, it is an electrician style VOM/clamp-meter. Do you have voltage probes for your Klein meter?

Comment: And yes it has probes and alligator clips and a clamp

Comment: If it is like the sockets in the US, and if it is wired correctly, the wider prong is neutral. You cannot verify that with a meter unless you have a ground conductor somewhere. Neutral will be the prong whose voltage is within a couple of volts of Ground. The hot wire will be 120V with respect to neutral and 120V with respect to ground. Note that "120" may not be exactly 120. But it will probably be between 100 and 130V.

Comment: @mkeith I think this is the answer. However, if there isn't a ground then any earthed surface (like a water pipe or sewer) would work. Neutral may be more volts than expected,  maybe enough to be dangerous, but it should have no significant AC component

Comment: @crasic: "*Neutral ... should have no significant AC component.*" This isn't quite right. If there is voltage on the neutral it will most likely be AC. If it's dangerous then it will be significant. What were you trying to say?

Comment: You say you need to know which is Live and Neutral but not why you need the info. You said you are connecting a power unit. What power unit it is (make, model, preferably a link to product manual) ? Are you aware that many countries use non-polar sockets so at the device it may or may not be swapped and many devices (but maybe not yours) don't care which is Live and Neutral? Does the power unit require earth connection? If it does, you seriously should not wire it to 2-prong plug, unless you know the risks and are willing to take them. What will the power unit give power to?

Answer (score -1):

Ground is Earth is the best reference for Vac(~), but not the only way to measure.

On this old socket it should be the metal housing and screw attached.

[image]

Neutral ought to be < 5% of line voltage wrt. earth gnd.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but the socket doesn't have a screw. It's like a new plastic type. I'm also wondering that even if I do find out which is live in this socket I'll have to figure it out for each socket I try it on. I need to power a "Power Unit" that will produce 24vdc from the 120Vac and it takes loose wire connections.  So testing each socket is the only way, right?

Comment: Line is the smaller slot in socket but normally it wont matter.

Comment: Yeah if it's a normally wired socket but I would always want to double check. I guess that contact voltage detector is the best option

Comment: normally it wont matter for an AC transformer input. But it matters for offline non isolated types.